# Get number of products faster

Tags: ce-1.7.0.2, product, database, mysql

I get the number of products:

```
Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()->count()
```

But this takes >10 seconds. Maybe because indexer is running or what ever. Can I query a table directly to get this count faster?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try this.

```
Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()->getSize()
```

When using `count` the full collection is loaded. For `getSize()` magento uses a separate sql. But this ignores any limit you set on the collection.
If you need a limit then use this:

```
count($collection->getAllIds());
```

This still executes an sql to get all the ids but it ignores the other attributes and fields.

Comment: But I am getting `getSize()` as `128` constantly even it does have 128 products.what problem with my magento?It shows only when `flat product` option is set as `yes`.

Answer (score 4):

Instead of using `count()` use `Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()->getSize();`

Note : When you use `count()` magento will load all the items of the collection from the database.

Comment: But `getSize()` returns unexpected value when `flat category` option is `yes` in admin.

Answer (score 2):

```
    $collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();
    $collection
        ->addAttributeToFilter('price', array('gt'=> 100)) //you can add any filter
        ->getSelect()
        ->reset(Zend_Db_Select::COLUMNS)
        ->columns(new Zend_Db_Expr("Count(`entity_id`) as `products_count`"));

    print_r($collection->getData());
```

Comment: This is needlessly complicated compared to the other answers. Magento supports OP's required feature out-of-the-box, no need to come up with a complicated bypass of the Model layer.